# how to use or / || in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to echo a message if one of 2 statements are true. In this case to do: echo("It's the weekend!!! Party Time!!");   if   ($today == "Saturday") or this ($today == "Sunday") is true.

The code looks like this:

```
$today = "insertCurrentDayHere";

if ($today == "Friday"){
    echo("It's Friday! Have an awesome weekend!!");
}elseif ($today == "Saturday") || ($today == "Sunday"){
    echo("It's the weekend!!! Party Time!!");
}elseif ($today == "Monday"){
    echo("Shit, it's Monday again..."):
}else{
    echo("Another regular day right? Good luck.");
}
```

it's the || that gives me an error when trying to run it. I've tried to find a guide for this but can't find one so I'm asking here.
thanks for help.

Comment: And what error does it give you?

Comment: You need `()` around _all_ of `(($today == "Saturday") || ($today == "Sunday"))`

Comment: Review [the official docs on flow control statement syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Comment: You don't need brackets on `echo`, btw. It's a keyword, not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
elseif ($today == "Saturday") || ($today == "Sunday")
```

The entire condition needs to be wrapped in parenthesis:

```
elseif (($today == "Saturday") || ($today == "Sunday"))
```

Comment: Also possible: `elseif ($today == "Saturday" || $today == "Sunday")`

Comment: This is exactly what I was loking for, thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `switch` statement.

```
switch($today){
    case "Friday":
     echo("It's Friday! Have an awesome weekend!!");
    break;
    case "Saturday":
    case "Sunday":
      echo("It's the weekend!!! Party Time!!");
    break;
    case "Monday":
      echo("Shit, it's Monday again...");
    break;
    default:
       echo("Another regular day right? Good luck.");
}
```

Comment: Does that work in php? I thought that was like Java. idk